# R trying to create a counter when one value in a dataframe is greater than a value in a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

So I have these values:

[image]

This dataframe is 56,000 rows x 1 column

and

[image]

this matrix is has 56,000 rows and 2 columns

essentially what i want to do is compare how many times the value in row of the data frame is greater than the value in the row in the matrix.

EX: 8.34 > 2.05, so i is incremented by 1, then 8.34 > -9.15, i is incremented by 1 again. 4.902 > .87, i incremented by 1 again.

So this is my code:

```
#Question 3 count times observed is different than null
compareObservedNull = function(x, set1, set2){
  i = 0
  if(x[set1] > x[set2]){
    i = i + 1
  }
}

observedGreaterNum = apply(MARGIN = 1, 
              FUN = compareObservedNull,
              tOBSERVEDDF,
              tNullDistributionMatrix)
```

When running my code I get

```
Error in x[set1] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Is there a function implemented in R to compare values at the row level?

Comment: If I understood you problem correctly you could just cbind the two data.frames, perform the operation to get the value per line and then cumsum? What is supposed to happen when the value in df1 is smaller than one or both of df2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all you is to get the number of times a value `df[i]` is greater then the `mat[i,j]` a solution would be to convert the data.frame (after adding a second column equal to the first) into a matrix and compare it with the matrix and sum up the resulting logical vector. One thing you gotta keep in mind in R is that most baseR function are vectorised especially the basic ones `[, +, *, -, >, ==` ....

```r
df$V2 = df$V1
sum(as.matrix(df) > mat)
#> [1] 175
```

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(100, 4,4))
mat <- matrix(rnorm(200), nrow=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe is called `dat` with column name `col_name` and matrix `mat` you could do :

```
dat$result <- rowSums(dat$col_name > mat, na.rm = TRUE)
```

`result` will have count of number of values in `col_name` which is greater than respective row value in `mat`.

If you want to count total values you can `sum` the new column.

```
sum(dat$result)
```